# Calculus problem with births and generations

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Assume that  in a country $A$ there are $8.000.000$ people in the present generation and every couple gives birth  to $1.3$ children in average.We also assume that the  anology $1.3$ in every couple will continue to exist in the future.

Can we find when this society will vanish(the number of people will be strictly smaller than 2)?
How many people overall will live in this society until then?

I believe this is a problem where i have to use the notion of function and derivative and study its behavior.

But i cannot find the appropriate function for this.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any notion of death and time? Or do we assume that at each time interval, a couple produces 1.3 children, and dies?

Comment: Unforunately these are tho only given conditions in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that at each successive time $t(\in\Bbb Z)$, a couple produces $1.3$ children, and dies. Then, the function would be strictly decreasing - $$N(t+1)=N(t)\times\frac{1.3}{2}, N(0)=8,000,000\\\implies N(t)=8000000\cdot\left(\frac{13}{20}\right)^t$$Then the population would die when $N(t)<2$, which happens when $$t>35.2887832\\\implies t=36$$
Then the total number of people who have ever lived is $$\sum_{t=0}^{36} N(t)$$which can be computed with a geometric series.

Since I have used a discrete model, there is no calculus involved. If it had been modelled with continuous time, then an integral would have been necessary at the end.